# Red squares with minted and mathescape=true

Tags: xetex, minted

Using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,mathescape=true]{http}
POST /shop/28/Shop.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: mdsec.net
|\textbf{Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded}|
Content-Length: 20
|$\dlsh$|
quantity=1\&price=449
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

I get red squares around every character after `|`. Why?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: These square boxes are because the pygmentize lexer reported the tokens as error tokens for the used lexer, here http.